# How to write an SQL query to genearte the empty json objects inside json object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server-2019

I need an SQL query to get the below JSON object. I tried with `FOR JSON PATH`. Upto Model object I can get it. But inside JSON objects are not coming.

```
{
  "Model": [
    {
       "ModelName": "Registration",
       "Version": 1,   
       "Student": [
          {
            "StudentID": null,
            "StudentName": null,          
            "Work": [
              {
                "WorkID": null,
                "WorkNameName": null,             
                "Note": [
                  {
                    "NoteID": null,
                    "Comments": null,                 
                    "Visible": [
                       {
                         "IsVisible": null
                       }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
           ]
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: @zealous  
I just need the above json object in the select statement.

`DECLARE @ScriptData NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ScriptData = SELECT(-----------);

SELECT @Scriptdata`

The above select need to return the Json object.

Comment: please show us how you tried to get the object.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I tried the below query.. But inside json objects, I need to get.

`DECLARE @ScriptData NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @ScriptData = (SELECT 'Registration' AS ModelName,                 
                       1 AS Version,
             JSON_QUERY('[]') AS Student       
        FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Model'), 
                                                              INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES);  
  SELECT @ScriptData`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  I think I got the answer. We can delcare the variable and keep it in JSON_QUERY.

Answer (score 0):

Defining an `nvarchar(max)` variable (which is a valid JSON object) is always an option, but you may try to format the query results from a `SELECT` statement as JSON using `FOR JSON AUTO`. In this case the structure of the output JSON depends on the structure of the SELECT statement.

Statement:

```
DECLARE @ScriptData nvarchar(max) 
SET @ScriptData = 
(
   SELECT 
      Model.ModelName, Model.Version, 
      Student.StudentID, Student.StudentName,
      Work.WorkID, Work.WorkNameName,
      Note.NoteID, Note.Comments,
      Visible.IsVisible
   FROM (VALUES ('Registration', 1)) Model (ModelName, Version)   
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULL, NULL)) Student (StudentID, StudentName)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULL, NULL)) Work (WorkID, WorkNameName)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULL, NULL)) Note (NoteID, Comments)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (NULL)) Visible (IsVisible)
   FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT('Model'), INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
)
```

Result:

```
{
  "Model":[
    {
      "ModelName":"Registration",
      "Version":1,
      "Student":[
        {
          "StudentID":null,
          "StudentName":null,
          "Work":[
            {
              "WorkID":null,
              "WorkNameName":null,
              "Note":[
                {
                  "NoteID":null,
                  "Comments":null,
                  "Visible":[
                    {
                      "IsVisible":null
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```